# What is the intuition behind A-λI?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is step one in a lot of problems I solve. It is a tool that I do not intuitively understand

- We care about when it's determinant is 0 because then we can find eigenvalues.
- We care about the kernel of resulting matrices after we substitute calculated eigenvalues in for λ.

Why is A-λI so magical?

Comment: Do you understand the eigenvalue problem? We're finding the solution of Ax=λx.

Comment: So then we are looking for a constant that can replace a linear transformation?

Comment: We're looking for such vectors x(the eigenvectors) and λ(the eigenvalues) satifies the equation, not a constant to replace a linear transformation. Solving eigenvalue problems can be useful, one example is the diagnozilation of matrix.

Answer (score -1):

The null space of $A-\lambda I$ is precisely the eigenspace $E_\lambda$ of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Heuristically, I tend to think of it in terms of "prevailing winds". On $E_\lambda$, applying $A$ just scales input vectors $v$ by $\lambda$. Now imagine adding a "headwind" to $A$ which subtracts $\mu$ times $v$. On $E_\lambda$, that means $v$ will be scaled by $\lambda - \mu$. If we picked $\lambda - \mu = 1$, everything in $E_\lambda$ would be still, i.e. fixed. That's great and all, but the "most important" subspace of a linear operation is its kernel, not its fixed space. So if we pick $\lambda - \mu = 0$, everything in $E_\lambda$ will be in the kernel, which will be effectively making $E_\lambda$ the most important subspace.